# Apache2 + Multiple Tomcat SSL

Tags: tomcat, mod-rewrite, apache2, mod-proxy

I'm currently looking for a solution to my little problem.

The Kolab solution is running on my Linux server on apache2.
All http request are redirected/rewrited to https and this should be ok and it runs fine.

so in that case http://example.com/* > https://example.com/*

now i configured 3 Tomcat's all of them maps to example.com/* 
(ContextPath="").

```
tc1 (web) - Http/Https (8087 | 8443)
tc2 (bamboo) - Http/Https (8085 | 8444)
tc3 (bitbucket/Git) - Http/Https (7990 | 8445)
```

i tryed with proxy_mod but it still fails. The Goal is to set :

```
tc1 > http://example.com > https://example.com
tc2 > http://bamboo.example.com >https://bamboo.example.com
tc3 > same tc2 with another subdomain
```

Apache2 > handle ssl by path example : example.com/roundcubemail otherwise let tomcat do that job

(Tc1) Config

```
<Connector port="8087" protocol="HTTP/1.1" 
connectionTimeout="20000"
URIEncoding="UTF-8" 
redirectPort="8443" />

<Connector port="8443" 
maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" 
SSLEnabled="true"
maxThreads="150" 
minSpareThreads="25" 
maxSpareThreads="75"
enableLookups="false" 
disableUploadTimeout="true" 
useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
acceptCount="100" 
scheme="https" 
secure="true"
clientAuth="false" 
sslProtocol="TLS" 
keystoreFile="${catalina.base}/conf/mykeystore.jks"
keystorePass="password123"
proxyPort="443"
proxyName="example.com"
/>
tc1 vhost :
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAdmin administrator@example.com
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / https://localhost:8443
ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:8443
</VirtualHost>

tc2 vhost :
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName bamboo.example.com
ServerAdmin administrator@example.com
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / https://localhost:8444
ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:8444
</VirtualHost>
```

In that case it won't work because it will redirect to apache2 in that case /var/www/html.
if i let tomcat rewrite then i get it working but the url's contain still the ports like https://example.com:8443/startpage
Anybody have an idea how to configure this setup or any other ideas how to get it work ?

Kind regards

Comment: If I understand your question, you need 3 VirtualHost on :80 (to handle the http-> https redirects), 3 more VirtualHost on :443 (to handle the HTTPS requests), and then 2 Connectors on each Tomcat (although I don't see why it is necessary to make Tomcat listen on both plain and SSL).